# sed command insert (i) from AppleScript

Tags: bash, sed, applescript

How do I do this:

```
# Insert a line "heater:M21789" before the line beginning with "fan"
$ sed '
/^fan/ i\
heater:M21789
' order789.txt
```

taken from http://unstableme.blogspot.com/2009/01/insert-append-change-lines-using-sed.html

Inside an AppleScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed the txt file for the example:

```
set theInput to "title:
PO for vessel unit1 const.
items:
fan:F34539
tube:L1245
driller:M4545
Description:
PO signed and verified by factory manager S K Lp
Date: Fri Jan 2 17:26:44 UTC 2009
Author: M Kumar"


set xxx to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of theInput & " | sed '
/^fan/ i\\
heater:M21789
'"

return xxx
```

or  strictly sticking to your example, for a file order789.txt in ~/

```
do shell script " cd ~; 
sed '
/^fan/ i\\
heater:M21789
' order789.txt"
```